# How to get the child element values of a xml parent node in c# asp.net(without using linq)

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I am having a xml file with nested elements. I need to load the xml file and save the values of a particular child elements to the sql database.

**xml File :**

```
    <section id="A00-A09">
          <desc>Intestinal infectious diseases (A00-A09)</desc>
          <diag>
            <name>A00</name>
            <desc>Cholera</desc>
            <diag>
              <name>A00.0</name>
              <desc>Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar cholerae</desc>
              <inclusionTerm>
                <note>Classical cholera</note>
              </inclusionTerm>
            </diag>
            <diag>
              <name>A00.1</name>
              <desc>Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar eltor</desc>
              <inclusionTerm>
                <note>Cholera eltor</note>
              </inclusionTerm>
            </diag>
            <diag>
              <name>A00.9</name>
              <desc>Cholera, unspecified</desc>
            </diag>
          </diag>
    </section>
     <section id="A15-A19">
          <desc>Tuberculosis (A15-A19)</desc>
          <includes>
            <note>infections due to Mycobacterium tuberculosis and Mycobacterium bovis</note>
          </includes>
        <diag>
            <name>A15</name>
            <desc>Respiratory tuberculosis</desc>
            <diag>
              <name>A15.0</name>
              <desc>Tuberculosis of lung</desc>
              <inclusionTerm>
                <note>Tuberculous bronchiectasis</note>
                <note>Tuberculous fibrosis of lung</note>
                <note>Tuberculous pneumonia</note>
                <note>Tuberculous pneumothorax</note>
              </inclusionTerm>
            </diag>
            <diag>
              <name>A15.4</name>
              <desc>Tuberculosis of intrathoracic lymph nodes</desc>
              <inclusionTerm>
                <note>Tuberculosis of hilar lymph nodes</note>
                <note>Tuberculosis of mediastinal lymph nodes</note>
                <note>Tuberculosis of tracheobronchial lymph nodes</note>
              </inclusionTerm>
              <excludes1>
                <note>tuberculosis s`enter code here`pecified as primary (A15.7)</note>
              </excludes1>
            </diag>
    </diag>
    </section>
```

I have loaded the xml but not able to get the values from the child elements since it is having same tag name. Do any one can help me to solve this issue

Comment: any specific reason you want to do this without linq? I think this task will be a lot harder without linq, especially because there are nested elements with same name. Please post some relevant codes you've tried, even if it failed.

Comment: Okay, can you give me a solution in linq

Comment: your xml file is not valid as posted (it has multiple root elements). Is that the actual format? *yes, that is the actual format*. Then we can't use linq in this case because the file can't be loaded as `XDocument` object. Otherwise, if xml file has one root and valid, we have a chance to use linq, and the question in this case is from which particular element you want to get the value?

Comment: The xml file starts with root <ICD10CM.tabular>. <Section> tag is child element. I need to fetch the <section> Desription(<desc>) and child tags of <section> values

Comment: which do you mean by child tags of <section>? It's not clear. please, edit the question and describe clearly output/value you expect to get from that sample xml.

Comment: Under <diag> tag, I need to fetch the values of <name> and <desc>, We need to fetch values if there is another child node for <diag>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following console application example demonstrates a way to get `<desc>` element that is direct child of `<section>` element, also to get `<name>` and `<desc>` under each `<diag>` element. I'm using [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from `System.Xml.Linq`. But not using linq query syntax as it isn't necessary in this case and you seems doesn't like it :

```
//load xml string
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
//or use XDocument.Load("path_to_xml_file.xml"); to load from file

//get all <section> element
var sections = doc.Root.Elements("section");
//get <desc> and all <diag> under each <section>
foreach (var section in sections)
{
    var desc = (string)section.Element("desc");
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("new Section. Desc: {0}", desc));
    var diags = section.Descendants("diag");
    foreach (var diag in diags)
    {
        var name = (string)diag.Element("name");
        var desc2 = (string)diag.Element("desc");
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("name: {0}, desc: {1}", name, desc2));
    }
}
```

notice that `Descendants()` is used to get any child of current element and `Element()` used to get only direct child of current element.